# LED driver PT4115: how to avoid arc around IC pins?

Tags: led, driver, arc

I built a LED driver with PT4115 IC. The board lighted LEDs up but sparks appeared around SW, VIN & GND pins after 10 seconds and the phenomenon didn't damage the IC. I recorded it by my mobile phone.

[Spark around pins](https://youtu.be/oiz6Y5YslXE)

Below is the schematic and the PCB board:
[image: schematic]
[image: PCB]

I removed R2, D2 and R3 so the DIM pin is floating. It should help us to concerntrate to this problem.

I checked every pin of the IC and didn't find any short or something wrong. I thought that something conductive around these pins and start to conduct after 10 seconds. It is very strange and confused me.

Any good suggestion?

Comment: You should not be seeing sparks here. Can you give a schematic of your circuit?

Comment: Why is C2 there?

Comment: According to the datasheet of PT4115. C2 helps to reduce flicking of LED. It is optional.

Comment: One thing I notice is your dimmer potentiometer is far too large. The voltage on the dim pin, according to the datasheet, should vary from 0 to 5V, and anything from 2.5V to 5V represents full brightness. That shouldn't cause this problem, but is probably something worth fixing.

Comment: Actually, maybe this is causing the problem. This IC's dimming input is not rated to handle more than 6V. I have no idea what it would do if you gave it more than 6V, but this circuit does give it more than 6V.

Comment: The datasheet also cautions against using a silicon diode for D3 (called D1 or D in the datasheet), because poor reverse recovery time and high voltage drop can cause high voltages to appear on the SW pin. Though it looks like the spark in the video is between CSN and GND.

Comment: D2 is a 3.3V zener and I shorted SW_A and SW_B when soldering so actually the voltage at DIM end is 0~3.3V. It satisfies the 0~2.5...5V rule.

Comment: My D3 is schottky diode SS24. I used normal diode symbol because I can't find suitable part in EAGLE.

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss, then. Without some measurements of what's going on at those pins (and I wouldn't want to stick an oscilloscope on anything that's sparking like that!) I'll have to leave this to someone else.

Comment: Is D3 backwards, by any chance?

Comment: Also, did the sparks occur during open circuit operation, or when the LED was connected?

Comment: 1. D3 is fine. I checked the circuit and PCB.
2. I tested the board with LED connected.
3. The board works fine even if sparks appear.

Comment: Can you post a bigger picture of the board. ANd are you sure that diode is not fried.

Comment: I added a bigger picture of the board and removed DIM-related components. It should help us to concerntrate to this problem.

Comment: Assuming the diode is still good, the layout of the board is really bad. That current sense line loops around the chip, crosses and runs parallel with the drive line. That's bad. The inductor is also a long way from the chip. The thing needs to be turned round 180 degrees. Vin also crosses v-out.....

Comment: To me it looks like there's flux between the pins, and there's current flowing through the flux.  It also seems to me that I see a wisp of smoke drifting over that chip when the sparking stops.  Use some alcohol to remove the flux, then let it get good and dry, then try it again.

Comment: I tried to use acetone + toluene + needle + toilet paper to clean pins of PT4115 carefully and sparks are gone. The root cause was that flux is conductive. Thanks JRE.

Comment: @BruceHsu layout still sucks... You will still be having big peaks on that pin. Sparks may be gone, but life will be questionable.

Comment: @BruceHsu So you used plumbing solder? That's a real problem - the acid is not only highly conductive but it's also corrosive. Try to clean it very well.

Comment: Where is input cap C1?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the diode is still good, the layout of the board is really bad.

That current sense line loops around the chip, crosses and runs parallel with the drive line. That's bad. The inductor is also a long way from the chip and Vin also crosses v-out..... .

The PT4115 needs to be turned round 180 degrees with that part layout. But in truth the whole layout needs redone.

More like this...

[image]

See also "Layout considerations" on page 14 of the [datasheet](https://people.xiph.org/~xiphmont/thinkpad/PT4115E.pdf).

Vital parts are:

> Minimize ground noise by connecting high-current ground returns,
>   the input bypass-capacitor ground lead, and the
>   output-filter ground lead to a single point (star ground
>   configuration).
>
> The SW pin of the device is a fast switching node, so
>   PCB tracks should be kept as short as possible.
>
> ...
>
> It is particularly important to mount the coil and the
>   input decoupling capacitor as close to the device pins as
>   possible to minimize parasitic resistance and inductance,
>   which will degrade efficiency.

Comment: BTW C1 is missing and should be located between the diode and the PT4115.

Answer (score 3):

Making an answer out of my comment:

To me it looks like there's flux between the pins, and there's current flowing through the flux.

It also seems to me that I see a wisp of smoke drifting over that chip when the sparking stops. That indicates that the problem is the flux.

Use some alcohol to remove the flux, then let it get good and dry, then try it again.

---

Given that cleaning the area around the chip fixed the sparking, it seems to have been correct.

It would still be a good idea to follow the suggestions in the other answers to improve the layout and to check the type and function of the diode.

Answer (score 1):

The sparks are inductor's way to keep the current on if all low voltage drop routes are off. Your diode D3 is bidirectionally non-conductive or disconnected.